# SQL: How to optimize many SELECTs on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, select, indexing

I have created a table with

```
CREATE TABLE xy (
blub VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
z INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (blub)
)
```

and want to query many entries at once by the column 'blub'. Currently I am using the simple query

```
SELECT blub, z FROM xy WHERE blub = '...'
```

which is much faster than

```
SELECT blub, z FROM xy WHERE blub = '...' OR blub = '...' OR '...
```

Is there any other way to make it faster and to merge all queries?

Comment: This question answers this pretty well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510395/sql-server-in-or-or-which-is-fastest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try an `in` clause.  I'm not certain it will be faster, but it will definitely be more succinct.  For example:

```
select blub, z from zy where blub in ('this', 'that', 'theother');
```

[`explain`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) will tell you which is actually fastest for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT blub, z FROM xy WHERE blub in ('a','b','c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IN` clause in your `WHERE` like this:

```
SELECT blub, z 
FROM xy 
WHERE blub IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

As far as which one runs better/faster you can use the query execution plan for the query.   In Sql-server you Click "Include Actual Execution Plan". In MySql, you could use the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an index

```
CREATE TABLE xy ( 
blub VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
z INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (xy),
KEY (blub,z)
)
```

If your table is already populated then do this

```
ALTER TABLE xy ADD INDEX (blub,z);
```

then, `SELECT blub, z FROM xy WHERE blub in ('a','b','c')` will be faster