# Difference between using 'in' and statements combined by 'or'

Tags: sql-server-2012

what is the difference between this two queries

```
select * from ggk where gid in (100,200,300,400,500);

select * from ggk where gid=100 or gid=200 or gid=300 or gid=400 or gid=500;
```

I know that the first one is easy to write and it is eventually converted to the second query. But that will decrease the performance if there are more parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no difference... in general using `IN` or `OR` lead to ignoring indexes

Comment: optimizer will read them the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server 'in' or 'or' - which is fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510395/sql-server-in-or-or-which-is-fastest)